# Is it a website's discretion to cancel and refund an order after it was shipped?

Tags: commerce

If a customer places an order on a website, later decides to cancel the order, but the website ships the order, is it the website's discretion whether or not to refund the customer?

Comment: Did the customer refuse delivery of the shipment?

Comment: It can also matter how much later, since there are laws allowing cancelling online orders (the "cooling-off" period: 3 business days for US federal rules).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the circumstance, however, if it is a typical sales website the common law position is that a contract is formed when they accept your offer - either by acknowledging acceptance in an email or dispatching the goods; at that point both parties are legally bound.

The actual terms of the contract May and probably will deal with returns and refunds but generally you do not have a common or statute law right to return goods unless they are faulty.